# Add Two Polynomials Java Program

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomials

I am working on this simple program that adds two polynomials. However, I am getting wrong results and could not spot the mistake.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Polynomial {

    private LinkedList<Term> terms = new LinkedList<Term>();


    private class Term {

        private int coef;
        private int exp;

        public Term(int coef, int exp) {
            this.coef = coef;
            this.exp = exp;
        }

        public int getCoef() {
            return coef;
        }

        public int getExp() {
            return exp;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return (this.coef + "x^" + this.exp);
        }
    }

    public String addPoly(String first, String second) {

        LinkedList<Term> otherTerms = new LinkedList<Term>();

        String result = "";

        String [] termsArray1 = first.split(";");
        String [] termsArray2 = second.split(";");

        for (int i = 0; i < termsArray1.length; i++) {
            String [] temp = termsArray1[i].split("x\\^");

            int currentCoef = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            int currentExp = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);

            Term currentTerm = new Term(currentCoef, currentExp);
            terms.add(currentTerm);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < termsArray2.length; i++) {
            String [] temp = termsArray2[i].split("x\\^");

            int currentCoef = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            int currentExp = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);

            Term currentTerm = new Term(currentCoef, currentExp);
            otherTerms.add(currentTerm);
        }

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

       while (true){

           if(i == terms.size() || j == otherTerms.size()) {
               break;
           }

           if(terms.get(i).getExp() < otherTerms.get(j).getExp()) {
              result += (otherTerms.get(j).toString() + ";");

               j++;
           }

           if(terms.get(i).getExp() > otherTerms.get(j).getExp()) {
               result += (terms.get(i).toString() + ";");

               i++;
           }

           if(terms.get(i).getExp() == otherTerms.get(j).getExp()) {
               Term temp = new Term((terms.get(i).getCoef() + otherTerms.get(j).getCoef()), terms.get(i).getExp());
               result += (temp.toString() + ";");
               i++;
               j++;
           }
       }

       result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
       return result;
    }
}
```

::Test::

String s3 = "5x^2;-4x^1;3x^0";

String s4 = "6x^4;-1x^3;3x^2";

Polynomial p = new Polynomial();

System.out.println(p.addPoly(s4, s3));

Expected result: 6x^4;-1x^3;7x^2;-4x^1;3x^0

Actual result: 3x^4;7x^2;-1x^1;10x^0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your loop exits, one of the following can still be true:

- `i < terms.size()`
- `j < j == otherTerms.size()`

And this is the case with your example input. This means that part of one of the terms has not been processed and integrated into the output.

A second problem is that your multiple `if` statements are not exclusive; after the first  `if` block is executed and `j++` has executed, it might well be that `j` is an invalid index in `otherTerms` when the second `if` is evaluated. This should be avoided by turning the second and third `if` into `else if`.

Here is a fix for that loop:

```
    while (i < terms.size() || j < otherTerms.size()) {
        if(i == terms.size() || j < otherTerms.size() && terms.get(i).getExp() < otherTerms.get(j).getExp()) {
            result += (otherTerms.get(j).toString() + ";");
            j++;
        }
        else if(j == otherTerms.size() || i < terms.size() && terms.get(i).getExp() > otherTerms.get(j).getExp()) {
            result += (terms.get(i).toString() + ";");
            i++;
        } 
        else if(terms.get(i).getExp() == otherTerms.get(j).getExp()) {
            Term temp = new Term((terms.get(i).getCoef() + otherTerms.get(j).getCoef()), terms.get(i).getExp());
            result += (temp.toString() + ";");
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

#### Better approach

Your approach is not really OOP. Ideally, the first expression should serve to create one instance of `Polynomial` and the other expression should serve to create another instance of `Polynomial`. Then there should be a method that can add another `Polynomial` instance to the own instance. Finally there should be a `toString` method that returns the instance as a string in the required format. Your driver code would then look like this:

```
        Polynomial a = new Polynomial("5x^2;-4x^1;3x^0");    
        Polynomial b = new Polynomial("6x^4;-1x^3;3x^2");
        Polynomial sum = a.addPoly(b);
        System.out.println(sum.toString());
```

This is much more object oriented, and will automatically avoid the code repetition that you currently have.